# how to change integer variable in struct?

Tags: c

when we want to change the value of the string variable in struct we use strcpy().
now if we want to change int value what should we use because when I doing

```
int val; scanf("%d", val);
emp.age = val;
printf("updated successfully.");
```

it gives me a run time error

Comment: Please take a step back, and go back to whatever book or tutorial you're reading. Do they really say that this is the way to call `scanf`? You're not missing anything from the books or tutorials?

Comment: Besides that, you don't need the temporary `val` variable, you can read directly into the structure member: `scanf("%d", &emp.age);`

Comment: Activate compiler warnings

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
int val; scanf("%d", val);
```

This:

```
int val; scanf("%d", &val);
```

`scanf` needs an address to store what has been read by `%d`.  Without that `&` on `val`, `scanf` will interpret the value of `val` as an address.  In this case, `val` hasn't even been initialized, so undefined behavior all the way.

Be glad it crashes instead of corrupting your program in other mysterious ways.

Comment: oooooh!! I was coding all night. I think I should take a rest now. thank you.

Comment: if you found the comment helpful, don't forget to upvote or accept it.

Comment: And... if you enable compiler warnings `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS (check options for other compilers), your compiler would have told you exactly what the problem was. (in fact I would be surprised if you were not received an incompatible type error)

Answer (score 1):

its nothing special in `struct`. you just need to know the `syntax` of accessing it members.

e.g. consider the person struct below:

```
struct person{
  int   val;
  char* str;
};

struct person per;

struct person* p_per;  /*its a pointer to struct person*/
```

now lets access and assign values to each one of them

```
scanf("%d",&per.val); /*accessing via operator . */

scanf("%d", &p_per->val); /*cos its a pointer, we can access via operator ->*/

scanf("%d", &(*p_per).val); /*we can access also like this syntax. but its not often used*/
```